# Does ServiceStack.OrmLite load Views from Sql Server?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Does `ServiceStack.OrmLite` load `Views` from `Sql Server`?

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

Latest Version.

I have a few `Views` in my Database and I would like to load them using `ServiceStack.OrmLite` are they being considered like `Tables` in `ServiceStack`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServiceStack.OrmLite` translates an object represented query into a SQL query.
So, if you can call your view from a SQL string (which is the case) then you can do it with `ServiceStack.OrmLite`

Comment: With OrmLite you don't need to use a normal Sql command. If you use a Sql Command you are loosing the power of this micro-ORM.

Comment: So, which command do I use? Do I need to include: :IhasId<int> in the class?

Comment: Your class must match the View (same name) and the properties you want to get/set must have same name as column names (you can use [Alias] attribute if columns have a name not supported by compiler. Then just call something like Db.SingleById<MyView>(23); Please read https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite for more information